# How can i make an array of object to an an array of strings

Tags: node.js

I am having an api response displayed as below

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "_id": "61f29cfb23ff35136c98fdcc"
        },
        {
            "_id": "61f2ab6123ff35136c996839"
        },
        {
            "_id": "61f2ad1a23ff35136c998270"
        }
    ],
    "id": "61e2e09244d6583cdfead089"
}
```

This is the code for the response

```
exports.fetchCategoryChildren = async (req,res) => {
  const category = await Category
  .find({_id: req.params.id })
  .select('children._id')
  if (!category) return res.status(400).json('No category found');
  return res.json(_.head(category));
```

But i want a respone like this

```
            [
            "_id": "61f29cfb23ff35136c98fdcc",
            "_id": "61f2ab6123ff35136c996839",
            "_id": "61f2ad1a23ff35136c998270"
           ],
```

Because i want to use the response in an $in operator which takes an array.

How can i achieve my desired result?

Comment: If `_.head(category)` returns the referenced object, `_.head(category).children.map({_id} => _id)` will return the ID array.

Comment: The desired response could be EITHER: `[ { "_id" : "61f29cfb23ff35136c98fdcc" }, { "_id": "61f2ab6123ff35136c996839" },  { "_id": "61f2ad1a23ff35136c998270" } ]`, OR it could be: `[ "61f29cfb23ff35136c98fdcc", "61f2ab6123ff35136c996839", "61f2ad1a23ff35136c998270" ]`. Please edit & update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired output you want is not a valid JavaScript. You can have array of objects or array of strings.

Here is a code that returns an array of the ids, so the output will be:

```
["61f29cfb23ff35136c98fdcc", "61f2ab6123ff35136c996839", "61f2ad1a23ff35136c998270"]
```

```js
  const res = {
        "children": [
            {
                "_id": "61f29cfb23ff35136c98fdcc"
            },
            {
                "_id": "61f2ab6123ff35136c996839"
            },
            {
                "_id": "61f2ad1a23ff35136c998270"
            }
        ],
        "id": "61e2e09244d6583cdfead089"
    }

const mapped = res.children.map(child => child._id)

console.log(mapped)
// ["61f29cfb23ff35136c98fdcc", "61f2ab6123ff35136c996839", "61f2ad1a23ff35136c998270"]
```